# Is this expression true?

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis

Let $a_1=b_1/h,...,a_n=b_n/h\in\mathbb{R}$ with $h\in\mathbb{R}$ small. It's true that, given a $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$:
\begin{eqnarray}
(a_1+...+a_n)^\alpha=\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i)^\alpha+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{h^2}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
?? Is there any (good) reference where there is proof of some theorem / lemma that I can use to justify this?

Comment: This is false if $b_1=\cdots =b_n=1$ and $\alpha >2$.

Comment: You are asking in the wrong forum, I think.

Comment: There is a problem when $b_1 = h$, $b_2 = -h$, and $\alpha = -1$.  I think you're missing some constraints if you want this to be true.